# AlarmManager wont start activity

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am trying to use `AlarmManager` on Android to start an activity (say a sample 30 seconds into the future from the current time).

Here is what I have done so far:

- Defined an alarm manager instance.
- Created a custom `BroadcastReceiver` class with `onReceive` implemented to start the activity.
- Declared the receiver in the manifest.

The issue is even though the Receiver receives the intent and all debugging statements seem to indicate the activity will be started, it does not actually start. I have gone through pretty much all the threads here on SO, read through the Android developer documentation for `AlarmManager` but I am stuck. The code:

MainActivity.class:

```
Log.v(this.toString(), "Setting alarm for future.");
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
        try {
            Date nowDate = sdf.parse(String.valueOf(new Date()));
            Log.v(this.toString(), "Current date: " + nowDate.toString());
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(nowDate);
            calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
            Date futureDate = calendar.getTime();
            Log.v(this.toString(), "Alarm set for: " + futureDate.toString());
            Intent openAppIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, openAppIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, futureDate.getTime(), pendingIntent);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

AlarmReceiver.class:

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.v(this.toString(), "Inside onReceive.");
    Intent startActivityIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    startActivityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    Log.v(this.toString(), "Starting new activity.");
    context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(startActivityIntent);
    Log.v(this.toString(), "Activity should have started.");
}
```

}

Receiver is declared in the manifest like so:

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"/>
```

Any leads/help on this is most welcome.

Comment: There is minimum time limit (7 or 8 min)

Comment: @Style-7: really? can you please share a link to some documentation etc.? Coz it works. The other activity gets loaded, just doesnt seem to come into the foreground.

Comment: Starting from Android 10 apps in general cannot start Activity when they are in background. You probably should use Notification with fullScreenIntent. Refer to this https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts